# Closure compiler and PowerShell - How to "mute" warnings in console?

Tags: powershell, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to run the Closure Compiler from inside PowerShell:

```
& $javaPath -jar $closurePath --js $jsCombinedPath --js_output_file $jsMinifiedPath
```

It writes the minified file to `$jsMinifiedPath` *and* outputs that in console. If there are warnings then it throws them into console too.

Is there anyway to prevent it from writing to the console? I tried

```
& $javaPath -jar $closurePath --js $jsCombinedPath --js_output_file $jsMinifiedPath  | out-null
```

But it's not working (I'm new to PowerShell, so I'm not sure if this is right)

Answer (score 0):

Verify $jsMinifiedPath is not empty. The compiler will continue to use standard out if it is.